# Is MEF or MEF2 baked into the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, mef, mef2

I am trying to understand MEF and I am seeing references to MEF and MEF 2.

This [site](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) lists MEF2 as being much faster than MEF (4.0).

I need to understand what I am talking about when most people say MEF.

**So which is in the .NET Framework 4.5?  MEF or MEF2?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well to make it even more confusing Microsoft released three versions of MEF using two only unique names: MEF and MEF2

- System.ComponentModel.Composition.* MEF in .NET 4 (typically called just MEF), no support for CompositionScopes, ExportFactories, etc
- System.ComponentModel.Composition.* MEF2 in .NET 4.5 (sometimes called MEF2 or MEF), support for composition scopes, ExportFactories
- System.Compostion.* from independent package Microsoft.Composition lightweight version of MEF typically called MEF2

The benchmark site refers to lightweight MEF2 System.Compostion.* from Microsoft.Composition package.

Comment: There's also another one (latest as at April 2019) called [VS-Mef](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-mef). This would probably be the one to use, as its claimed to be the fastest of all the MEF versons, and more widely compatible with the now-many .NET version families.

Comment: VS Mef shows only better performance at startup: https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance/issues/120