# How to use dependency injection with MEF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mef

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 app and I have a number of `plugins` that I load through MEF. The simplified interface looks like this:

```
public interface IImportPlugin
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Category { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}
```

And a plugin class might look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IImportPlugin))]
public sealed class ImportCustomers : IImportPlugin
{
    private ICustomerService customerService;
    //Other services...

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ImportCustomers()
        : base()
    { 
        //Set properties
    }
}
```

How can I inject instances of the services into the plugin?

Comment: which version of mef are you using ?

Comment: @sayahimad 4.7.0

Comment: i need version of MEF not .Net Framework

Comment: @sayahimad Where do I find that?

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484403/is-mef-or-mef2-baked-into-the-net-framework

Comment: @sayahimad I referenced System.ComponentModel.Composition

Comment: that's mean you are using a MEF 1 .

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your question you have two solution either by using An Import Attribute or GetExports Methods .

**For Import (Importing By Constructor):**

```
[Export(typeof(IImportPlugin))]
public sealed class ImportCustomers : IImportPlugin
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;
    //Other services...

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ImportCustomers([Import(typeof(ICustomerService))] ICustomerService customerService)
      : base()
    { 
        //Set properties
        _customerService  = customerService ;
    }
}
```

**For GetExports :**

```
[Export(typeof(IImportPlugin))]
public sealed class ImportCustomers : IImportPlugin
{
    private ICustomerService _customerService;
    //Other services...

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ImportCustomers()
      : base()
    { 
        //You need to use your composition container
        //to resolve your instance using ICustomerService interface
        _customerService  = Container.GetExports<ICustomerService>()
                                     .Single().Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "GetExports"-version is called the Service-Locator Anti-pattern. You should not use it because it hides the dependencies of your `ImportCustomers`-class. Further, note that MEF also supports property injection.

Comment: @Georg thank you very much  for  your contribution :).

Comment: I don't understand, where is the magic that inject the Customer service when it is injected in the importing constructor using an Import attribute?

Comment: @JinsPeter concretely all the magic happens at the level of the container, which contains all the binaries through which MEF will be able to import and export through a mechanism of reflection based on import and export attribute.